# The claims get lost between login and the first time of use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I already read a lot of answers from people having kind of the same issue as me. Only difference is, that despite these questions and answers, I cannot get past this issue.

My issue is that, when I authenticate a user, primary through the facebook api, I add the claims I want to use, to the context, but when I want to use then in my controller ... then they are gone.
It is possible for me to save them in a session, but I really want to do it "the right way".

First, in my Startup.Auth.cs

```
            var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "1234",
            AppSecret = "abcd",
            Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    var rawUserObjectFromFacebookAsJson = context.User;
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }

        };
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

...then in my controller:

```
var currentIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
```

I want to make use of the access token here, but the claims only hold four values, which is the name and the id of the user, the email and what kind of provider I am using.

I think the last one maybe could be a clue, because it says ASP.NET Provider, but maybe I need some kind of Facebook provider?

Or .... it is possible, that I am doing something horrible wrong :-)

Comment: Hi Morten, did you ever find an answer for this issue?

Comment: Hey Francois. No, but if I remember correctly, I did some hacky-di-hack, to get it working, but unfortunately I cannot remember how. Sorry.